# Dataclasses - ¿Cómo crear clases sin tener que escribir tanto?

Tags: python, clase, python-3.7, diseño-de-clases

Tengo una aplicación donde debo crear muchas clases distintas. Para cada clase debo escribir el `__init__`, los *setters* y *getters*, las funciones de apoyo como `__repr__` y `__str__` y otras minucias burocráticas.

¿Hay una manera más corta de construir una clase?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Existe una manera corta de construir una clase con una implementación por default de los métodos que mencionas. Para ilustrar su uso, tomaremos como ejemplo una Clínica Dietética que necesita llevar un registro de pacientes con nombre, sexo y peso actual.

**Librería dataclasses**

La librería [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/es/3.7/library/dataclasses.html?highlight=dataclasses#module-dataclasses) es estándar desde Python 3.7, si bien [se puede utilizar en Python 3.6 instalando el módulo `dataclasses`](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/). Esta nos proporciona el *decorador* `dataclass` que anteponemos a la declaración de la clase. Con eso, la declaración misma se reduce a listar sus atributos, cada uno con su tipo según [PEP 526 -- Syntax for Variable Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Paciente:
    nombre: str
    peso: float
    sexo: str
```

(puedes usar `Any` como tipo cuando el atributo es de tipo indeterminado).

y con esto ya tenemos implementando el método `__init__`, los *setters* y *getters* para cada atributo y también el método tras la función `repr`.

```
pac1 = Paciente(nombre="Juan", peso=113.2, sexo="M")
pac2 = Paciente("Maria", 90, "F")
print(pac1) => Paciente(nombre='Juan', peso=113.2, sexo='M')
print(pac2) => Paciente(nombre='Maria', peso=90, sexo='F')
```

El método `__init__` declara sus parámetros con nombre en el mismo orden en que aparecen en la declaración de la clase. Los objetos se pueden instanciar pasando los parámetros por posición o por nombre. En este caso, la declaración generada es:

```
def __init__(self, nombre: str, peso: int, sexo: str):
    ...
```

**Valores por default**

Es posible indicar valores por default para cada atributo. Esto se hace escribiendo el signo "=" seguido de una expresión válida para el tipo de atributos.

Hagamos que el sexo por default para los pacientes sea "F":

```
class Paciente:
    nombre: str
    peso: float
    sexo: str = "F"

pac2 = Paciente("Maria", 90)
print(pac2) => Paciente(nombre='Maria', peso=90, sexo='F')
```

Primero deben escribirse los atributos sin valores por default, seguidos de todos los que tiene default.

**Ordenar y comparar**

Para fines de programar las clases de gimnasia, se necesita ordenar y clasificar los pacientes por peso. Para eso normalmente agregamos a la clase los métodos de comparación `__eq__`, `__lt__`, etc., pero es algo que `dataclasses` puede hacerlo por nosotros.

Para generar los métodos de comparación, `dataclasses` considera al objeto como una tupla de atributos (en el orden de su declaración) que se compara contra la tupla que representa al otro objeto (de la misma clase). La comparación sigue la reglas de la comparación de tuplas.

Entonces, si queremos comparar pacientes por peso, el atributo `peso` debe ser el primero en la declaración. También necesitamos indicar al decorador que genere los métodos de comparación necesarios. Para esto, pasamos el parámetro `order=True` al decorador

```
@dataclass(order=True)
class Paciente:
    peso: float
    nombre: str
    sexo: str = "F"

pac1 = Paciente(nombre="Juan", peso=113.2, sexo="M")
pac2 = Paciente(90, "Maria")
print(pac1 < pac2) => False
```

El decorador acepta varios parámetros con nombre (se muestran con su default):

```
@dataclass(init=True, repr=True, eq=True, order=False, unsafe_hash=False, frozen=False)
```

donde:

- `init` Generar método `__init__`
- `repr` Generar método `__repr__`
- `eq`   Generar método `__eq__`
- `order` Genera métodos `__lt__(), __le__(), __gt__(), __ge__()__`
- `frozen` Hace la clase inmutable.

**Métodos propios**

Nada impide agregar métodos propios a la clase. Por ejemplo, la implementación estándar de `str` se limita a llamar a `repr`, que no es lo mejor. Hagamos nuestra propia implementación:

```
@dataclass(order=True)
class Paciente:
    peso: float
    nombre: str
    sexo: str = "F"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.nombre}, {self.peso} kgs"

pac1 = Paciente(nombre="María", peso=98.3)
print(str(pac1)) => "María, 98.3 kgs"
```

**Configuración de atributos**

El método `field` nos permite configurar un atributo en particular de la clase. Con esto, la declaración completa de un atributo es:

```
nombre: tipo = field(default=MISSING, default_factory=MISSING, repr=True, hash=None, init=True, compare=True, metadata=None)
```

(Todos los parámetros son opcionales)

El parametro `init` determina si el campo será inicializado via `__init__` o es un campo generado internamente. Igualmente, `repr` marca si el campo debe incluirse al llamar a `__repr__` y `compare` si debe incluirse al generar las comparaciones `__lt__`, `__gt__`, etc.

El parámetro `default` aparece asignado con una variable *mágica* MISSING. Se usa esto de modo de poder distinguir "no tiene default" de "el default es None".

Alternativamente, el valor por default puede determinarse por una función sin parámetros especificada en "default_factory". Esta es llamada cada vez que se crea un objeto, y debe proporcionar el valor por default apropiado.

Ampliemos nuestra clase para incluir una lista de pesos semanales. Queremos que el atributo no sea incluido como parámetro de la creación, para forzar a que siempre se inicialice con una lista vacia.

La declaración

```
class Paciente:
    peso: float
    nombre: str
    sexo: str = "F"
    semanal: list = []  # Error!!!
```

es sintacticamente inválida, y nos previene del común error de compartir una lista sin querer entre todos los objetos de la clase Paciente. La forma correcta es usar el parámetro `default_factory` para indicar como generar una nueva lista por cada paciente:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass(order=True)
class Paciente:
    peso: float
    nombre: str
    sexo: str = "F"
    semanal: list = field(default_factory=list, init=False)
```

y luego

```
pac1 = Paciente(nombre="María", peso=98.3)
pac1.semanal.append(97.4)
pac1.semanal.append(96.5)
print(pac1.semanal) => [97.4, 96.5]
```

**Métodos de utilidad**

Los métodos `asdict` y `astuple` permiten obtener el objeto como diccionario o tupla, respectivamente:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, asdict, astuple

@dataclass(order=True)
class Paciente:
    peso: float
    nombre: str
    sexo: str = "F"
    semanal: list = field(default_factory=list, init=False)

pac1 = Paciente(nombre="María", peso=98.3)
print(asdict(pac1)) => {'peso': 98.3, 'nombre': 'María', 'sexo': 'F', 'semanal': []}
print(astuple(pac1)) => (98.3, 'María', 'F', [])
```

El método generado `__init__` ejecuta por default el método `__post_init__()` si está definido. La idea es poder completar la inicialización después de que `__init__` reciba sus parametros.

Agreguemos a nuestra clase código que inicialize la lista de pesos semanales con el peso inicial de la persona.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, asdict, astuple

@dataclass(order=True)
class Paciente:
    peso: float
    nombre: str
    sexo: str = "F"
    semanal: list = field(default_factory=list, init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.semanal.append(self.peso)

pac1 = Paciente(nombre="María", peso=98.3)
print(asdict(pac1)) => {'peso': 98.3, 'nombre': 'María', 'sexo': 'F', 'semanal': [98.3]}
print(astuple(pac1)) => (98.3, 'María', 'F', [98.3])
```

Espero que les haya sido útil.

Comment: Excelente descubrimiento

Comment: No tenia idea de este decorador, muchisimas gracias por esta respuesta, +10 y si pudiera te gastaría un café, estimado.

Comment: edité indicando el backport a Python 3.6 vía el módulo dataclasses (`pip install dataclasses`)