# Terminar un programa en python

Tags: python

Programa que sea capaz de controlar un almacén, en el cual debe controlar las entradas de `n` cantidad de artículos, debe controlar la salida `n` cantidad de artículos, y se debe mostrar un reporte de artículos el cual está integrado por número de artículo, precio unitario, nombre, descripción del artículo, y unidad de medida.

El programa debe ser elaborado con uso de funciones con paso de parámetros y argumentos.

Bueno el caso es que ya tengo todo, me da la entrada, la salida, el reporte de los artículos, pero el problema es que cuando me da el reporte solo me lo da de un articulo, por decir si en el almacén quedan 3 artículos y quiero el reporte de ellos solo me pega el mismo articulo

¿Habra alguien que me pueda decir como corregir eso en mi programa por favor?

Este es el programa es Python, es en donde dice `def Reporte_Almacen`

```py
def Entrada_Almacen(Cantidad):
    global Contador
    global Art_Nombre
    global Art_PrecioUnit
    global Art_Caract
    global Art_Unid

    for i in range(Cantidad):
        print("Articulo a ingresar numero: "+ str(i+1))
        Art_Nombre = input ("Nombre del articulo: ")
        Art_PrecioUnit = int(input("Precio unitario del articulo:$"))
        Art_Caract = input("Caracteristicas del articulo: ")
        Art_Unid =input("Unidad de medida del producto: ")
    Contador=Contador+Cantidad
    return Contador

def Salida_Almacen(Cantidad):
    global Contador

    if Cantidad <= Contador:
        Contador=Contador-Cantidad
    else:
        print("Sólo existe "+str(Contador)+ "Articulos en almacen")
        return Contador

def Reporte_Almacen():
    global Contador
    for i in range (Contador):
        print("La cantidad de articulos en el almacen es: ",Contador)
        print("Nombre del articulo: ",Art_Nombre)
        print("Precio unitario del articulo:$ ",Art_PrecioUnit)
        print("Caracteristicas del articulo: ",Art_Caract)
        print("Undidad de medida del articulo: ",Art_Unid)
    return Reporte_Almacen


op=0
Contador=0
Art_Nombre= " "
Art_PrecioUnit=0
Art_Caract= " "
Art_Unid=" "

while (op<=4):
    print(" MENÚ DE ALMACEN")
    print("1.ENTRADA de articulos")
    print("2.SALIDA de articulos")
    print("3.REPORTE de articulos")
    print("4. SALIR ")
    op=int(input("Selecciona un opción del 1 al 4: "))

    if(op==1):
        print("ENTRADA DE ARTICULOS")
        Cantidad=int(input("Cuantos articulos deseas INGRESAR al almacen: "))
        Regreso=Entrada_Almacen(Cantidad)
        print("La cantidad de articulos en el almacen es: ",Regreso)

    if(op==2):
        print("SALIDA DE ARTICULOS")
        Cantidad = int(input("Cuantos articulos deseas retirar del almacen: "))
        Regreso=Salida_Almacen(Cantidad)
        print("La cantidad de articulos en el almacen AHORA es de: ",Regreso)

    if(op==3):
        print("REPORTE DE ARTICULOS")
        Reporte_Almacen()

    if(op==4):
        print("HAS SALIDO DEL MENÚ")
        break

    if (op>=5):
        print("ERROR, Elije una opción del 1 al 4, PORFAVOR")
        op=0
```

Este es un ejemplo de como me hace el reporte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo que pasa es que el valor de las variables se sobre escribe, si quieres guardar multiples datos, se usan las listas. para tu caso se tendria que cambiar de estructura de dato a un diccionario

Answer (score 2):

La razón por la que sólo imprime un artículo es que tu código sólo maneja **un** artículo: el último ingresado.

```
def Reporte_Almacen():
    global Contador
    for i in range (Contador):
        print("La cantidad de articulos en el almacen es: ",Contador)
        print("Nombre del articulo: ",Art_Nombre)
        print("Precio unitario del articulo:$ ",Art_PrecioUnit)
        print("Caracteristicas del articulo: ",Art_Caract)
        print("Undidad de medida del articulo: ",Art_Unid)
    return Reporte_Almacen
```

Lo que falta es una estructura de datos que almacene la información de un artículo (precio unitario, etc.), para la cual viene de perillas una clase, la que crearemos usando `dataclasses`

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Articulo:
    nombre: str
    precio: float
    caracteristicas: str
    unidad: str
    existencia: float = 0.0
```

Esto simplifica la creación de la clases con sus métodos por default. Revisa está respuesta para más información: [Dataclasses](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/450135/dataclasses-c%c3%b3mo-crear-clases-sin-tener-que-escribir-tanto).

```
articulo1 = Articulo("Harina", 1.2, "15% Humedad", "KG")
articulo2 = Articulo("Azúcar", 0.5, "Granulada", "KG")
```

Voy a crear y poblar un diccionario llamado `inventario` para contener los artículos. La llave será el nombre del artículo

```
inventario = {}
inventario[articulo1.nombre] = articulo1
inventario[articulo2.nombre] = articulo2
```

Teniendo la información en un diccionario, generar el reporte es cosa de ir recorriendo sus valores:

```
def Reporte_Almacen(bodega):
    for articulo in bodega.values():
        print("La cantidad de articulos en el almacen es: ", articulo.existencia)
        print("Nombre del articulo: ", articulo.nombre)
        print("Precio unitario del articulo:$ ", articulo.precio)
        print("Caracteristicas del articulo: ", articulo.caracteristicas)
        print("Undidad de medida del articulo: ",articulo.unidad)
        print()
```

**Demo**

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Articulo:
    nombre: str
    precio: float
    caracteristicas: str
    unidad: str
    existencia: float = 0.0


articulo1 = Articulo("Harina", 1.2, "15% Humedad", "KG")
articulo2 = Articulo("Azúcar", 0.5, "Granulada", "KG")

inventario = {}
inventario[articulo1.nombre] = articulo1
inventario[articulo2.nombre] = articulo2

def Reporte_Almacen(bodega):
    for articulo in bodega.values():
        print("La cantidad de articulos en el almacen es: ", articulo.existencia)
        print("Nombre del articulo: ", articulo.nombre)
        print("Precio unitario del articulo:$ ", articulo.precio)
        print("Caracteristicas del articulo: ", articulo.caracteristicas)
        print("Undidad de medida del articulo: ",articulo.unidad)
        print()

Reporte_Almacen(inventario)
```

produce

```
La cantidad de articulos en el almacen es:  0.0
Nombre del articulo:  Harina
Precio unitario del articulo:$  1.2
Caracteristicas del articulo:  15% Humedad
Undidad de medida del articulo:  KG

La cantidad de articulos en el almacen es:  0.0
Nombre del articulo:  Azúcar
Precio unitario del articulo:$  0.5
Caracteristicas del articulo:  Granulada
Undidad de medida del articulo:  KG
```

Con esta ayuda puedes reorganizar tu programa para lograr el resultado deseado.