# Iniciar una clase con dataclass en que los atributos son objetos que yo he creado

Tags: python, poo

Estaba programando un BlackJack y decidí hacer una segunda versión utilizando **clases** con **dataclass**.

En las clases normales no hay problema.

```
@dataclass
class Carta:
    palo: str = ''
    figura: str = ''
    valor: int = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.figura}{self.palo} ({self.valor})'


@dataclass
class Barajador:
    barajas: list = field(default_factory=list, init=False)
    monton: list = field(default_factory=list, init=False)
    baraja: list = field(default_factory=list, init=False)


@dataclass
class Personaje:
    mano: list = field(default_factory=list, init=False)
    nombre: str = ''
    valor_de_mano: int = 0
    ganado = int = 0
```

Quería crear una clase que inicialice el juego y ahí agrupar las funciones del control del juego.
El problema surge al intentar inicializar los objetos que yo creé.

Después de buscar información y muchas pruebas decidí utilizar esta forma:

```
@dataclass
class Partida:  
    balance = 0     #   Ganado - perdido
    apuesta = 0     #   Apuestas
    ronda = 0       #   Num. de ronda
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.jugador = Personaje()  # Crea jugador
        self.jugador.nombre = 'Jugador'
        self.casino = Personaje()  # Crea casino
        self.casino.nombre = 'Casino'
        self.baraja2r = Barajador()  # Crea Barajador (máquina de dar y barajar)
```

**Funcionar funciona,** pero mi pregunta es si es una forma adecuada  o cuál sería la forma de hacerlo

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Dataclasses - ¿Cómo crear clases sin tener que escribir tanto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/450135/dataclasses-c%c3%b3mo-crear-clases-sin-tener-que-escribir-tanto)

Comment: Es lo primero que leí, explicas muy bien todo el funcionamiento, pero no supe trasladar la deferencia entre una lista y un objeto creado por mí

Comment: No hay diferencias; ambos son objetos.

Comment: Gracias @CandidMoe. En algo me había confundido al implementarlo y la información que encontraba entre campos mutables , inmutables..., me resultaba incomprensible